# How to Generate ipa file using terminal commands

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, terminal

How to Generate ipa file using terminal commands , The p12 certificate and mobile-provision certificates also configure through commands , It is possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using "jenkins" with "shenzhen" (in an "Execute shell") could be a good idea. Link to Shenzhen https://github.com/nomad/Shenzhen (you can try it out in the terminal without jenkins)

Comment: Yes , I want generate ipa with out using jenkins ,can you please share any urls for terminal commands

Comment: @srinivasn- I have given the link in the answer :) https://github.com/nomad/Shenzhen

Comment: I try to Install Shenzhen , using this command " $ gem install shenzhen " in terminal , I got "command not found" , Can you please explane how to use Shenzhen , other wise send me any document for Shenzhen